# How to emulate d3.js homepage?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

On d3.js homepage, http://d3js.org/, any source code or examples on how the interactive hexagons are created? In particular, I have a set of photos and I'd like to create the same effect. i.e. on mouse hover, the tiles move a little and the hovered tile is highlighted.

Comment: _"Any source code?"_ Yes! Just view the source! In this case, it appears to be using [hexbin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/hexbin)

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4330486) and [this plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/hexbin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the html source code, they use d3.js (of course) and d3hexbin.js, which is a library able to create and animate hexagons.

You can take a look on the code used in this page (thanks to dev tools) to learn how they use it.